# Ubuntu 18.04 Freezing on SSH and RDP but can still ping and very rare slow SSH with cryptic Python errors

Tags: ubuntu, python, crash

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a desktop which I connect to remotely via xRDP and sometimes SSH. The computer is in a hospital lab, which I connect to using a VPN. With no warning or pattern, when I am programming over the RDP connection, the desktop will freeze on RDP and I will not be able to SSH in (almost every time). This forces me to commute to the lab amidst the COVID concerns, which is supposed to be closed. :/

This most recent time however, my SSH has connected again after the freeze. The response times to what I am typing is 30+ seconds lag. I saw the following:

```
Last login: Wed Mar  4 16:01:39 2020 from 111.11.1.111
htop
^CFailed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
^Ctop
user:~$ top
^C
^C
^C^C^C
user:~$ Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/io.py", line 52, in <module>
^C
user:~$ top
^C
user:~$ sudo reboot
    import abc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _weakrefset import WeakSet
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/io.py", line 52, in <module>Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/io.py", line 52, in <module>  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
^A^C^C  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556, in _init_module_attrs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 409, in cached
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 364, in _get_cached
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 294, in cache_from_source
^C^CKeyboardInterrupt
[sudo] password for user:

user:~$ uptime
 00:46:27 up 2 days,  2:22,  1 user,  load average: 190.28, 185.42, 162.91
user:~$ sudo reboot -f
```

Tried running `top` to see what was running, no results came back. I see `uptime` is showing incredibly high loads, which might explain the delay on SSH commands.

1. How do I figure out what is happening?
2. Is there anyway to remotely force a reboot? I know I can send a WoL packet to start it from sleep, but don't think there's anything for reboot. Even just a one-liner I can set up and SSH to the box and wait for it to eventually be executed. I'm almost thinking to rig up a Pi to switch the power, or getting an UPS to control remotely at this point.

Comment: Load average 190? Sounds like you've got a programming mistake that we used to call a "fork bomb": a process which forks off new processes which fork off new processes which...  Top may not show them to you because they are each taking minuscule CPU. Use `ps awf` instead.

Comment: I was seeing entries in syslog mentioning Jetbrains and PyCharm. I didn't think fork bombs were that common to run into in Python.

Comment: Perhaps, but I wouldn't rule it out. Python is plenty powerful enough to shoot oneself in the foot. For instance: 
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess, sys
while True:
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, sys.argv[0]])

Answer (score 0):

## Use the Linux Watchdog Timer

There are third steps:

1. sudo apt install watchdog
2. sudo gedit /etc/watchdog.conf

   Uncomment the lines which refer to the `max-load` by removing the <kbd>#</kbd> from the beginning of the line. Save and exit.
3. sudo systemctl restart watchdog

Your machine is now protected by the Linux watchdog and will reboot automatically the next time the load goes too high.

#### Explanation

You can use the **watchdog timer** builtin to the Linux kernel to automatically reboot when things go haywire. Once set, the watchdog timer counts down and will reboot the system if it is not reset before hitting zero. So, you just need something that will periodically reset the timer: enter the **watchdog daemon**:

```bsh
sudo apt install watchdog
```

That installs watchdogd, a userspace daemon which does some tests to make sure the system is okay and tells the kernel **timer** to go back to sleep for another 60 seconds. If those tests fail or they take longer than 60 seconds, the system reboots.

It is very configurable. Just edit `/etc/watchdog.conf`. For example, here's a stanza (by default commented out) which would have detected the extremely high load average of 190 you reported:

```
# Uncomment to enable test. Setting one of these values to '0' disables it.
# These values will hopefully never reboot your machine during normal use
# (if your machine is really hung, the loadavg will go much higher than 25)
#max-load-1             = 24
#max-load-5             = 18
#max-load-15            = 12
```

#### Further reading

- The watchdog daemon manual: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/watchdog.8.html
- The watchdog daemon configuration file: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/watchdog.conf.5.html

Note: Do not worry about "hardware" versus "software" watchdogs. The software watchdog builtin to the Linux kernel is only slightly less reliable than a hardware watchdog. In your case, where the load average was simply extremely high, the software watchdog is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a pretty good safeguard but I wasn't able to get it figured out this morning. Might try again if the problem persists. Not what my motherboard chip is or how to find out, and whether or not that supports hardware watchdog.

Comment: You don't need to worry about a hardware watchdog. The Linux Kernel has a software watchdog builtin. Technically, it is slightly less reliable, but it doesn't matter for your situation.

Comment: I've edited the answer to try to make it simpler. Let me know if you still have problems.